# Java Spring Boot: How to view the body of a service that fails?

Tags: java, spring, http, exception, error-handling

I'm developing a back-end application using Spring Boot and Java.
The application uses controllers to implement web services.
My services call **external services** (not developed by me), which can (of course) fail with various HTTP codes.
This is an example of a service that fails (I call it `myService`):

**Input:**

```
{
  "input": "wrongInput"
}
```

**Output** (status code: 400) **:**

```
{
    "error": "This is the description of the error"
}
```

In my application I have implemented a `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` to catch exceptions when services fail. In this way I can catch the possible `ServicePropagatedException`  use it however I want to show the client that an internal error (due to outside services and not me) has occurred.

Here's how I use the custom `MyPropagatedException` exception in code:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = { MyPropagatedException.class })
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handlePostePropagatedException(MyPropagatedException ex, WebRequest request) {
            
    ServicePropagatedException spe = (ServicePropagatedException)ex; // Casting to ServicePropagatedException 
    
    return handleExceptionInternal(ex, getResponse("PROPAGATE_ERROR", "WHAT_HAPPENED"), new HttpHeaders(), spe.getHttpStatus(), request);
}
```

My question is: spe.getHttpStatus() successfully captures **error code 400** from my `myService` service, but **how can I make the client also display the body** in which the error is described? I would like to access the information `"error": "This is the description of the error"` and manage it as I want (or show it to the client as it is, or change it at will).

Is it possible to get this body using `ServicePropagatedException`? Or is there another way to do it?

Comment: This exception `ServicePropagatedException` is sent by you .. right ?

Comment: If you are catching and rethrowing exception . Look for `getResponseBodyAsString` method in Exception that you are catching

Comment: What is tha class that have getResponseBodyAsString method? In Exception this method doesn't exist

Comment: @wishyouwerehere https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestClientResponseException.html

Comment: But is from RestClientResponseException, that is not ServicePropagatedException (ServicePropagatedException is the exception that I catch when the service response is not 200 OK)